# Disable Multi-Select CheckBox functionality in a ListView?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, listview

I'd like to disable the multi-select feature of a checkbox in a ListView. How do I do that?

Answer (score 10):

Set the selection mode (SelectionMode) to SelectionMode.Single.

```
listView1.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Controls.SelectionMode.Single;
```

Cheers.